# Jmeter 5.5 Log Unable to invoke factory method in class com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.logging.LoggerPanelAppender

Tags: debugging, jmeter, blazemeter

trying to execute on Jmeter 5.5 script that returns in the log, even if it is not blocking the execution so it's just annoying :

ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.logging.LoggerPanelAppender for element Logger: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.logging.LoggerPanelAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class com.blazemeter.jmeter.debugger.logging.LoggerPanelAppender
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:238)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:136)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1122)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1047)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1039)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:249)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:295)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:621)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:694)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:137)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:55)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.(JMeter.java:113)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:257)

Tried already running different versions of download manger (1.9, 1.6, 1.8) or other jar files. Tried also scripts with no reference except default plug-in. Still the issue is there.
Jmeter log has only INFO and a few WARNS.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Step-by-step debugger for Apache JMeter](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-debugger#step-by-step-debugger-for-apache-jmeter) is producing the error.

I cannot reproduce your issue using JMeter 5.5 and BlazeMeter Step-by-step Debugger 0.6, everything works just fine so it might be the case one of "jars" you're using causing the problem.

Use vanilla latest stable JMeter ([version 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) as of now) without plugins and the error should go away.

For debugging purposes you can use [Debug Sampler, Debug Post-Processor and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) combination